# Ubuntu 18.04 Recent Update

Tags: 18.04

I just got done updating Ubuntu OS 18.04 on desktop computer with updates & upgrade packages, however when I click on settings icon the system returns me to the login screen to log in again something is messed up, need help, please!

Comment: Is Nvidia used?

Comment: It is built into my Lenovo Desktop system that runs two operating systems windows 10 & Ubuntu, however never really had a problem before until now..
sorry about that wrong area..

Comment: This may not be your issue (eg. nvidia issue as Pilot6 suggested may be correct), but I'd suggest logging in via a text terminal and checking your free space (`df -hl`) esp. in your $HOME (user directory). If insufficient space is available for needed workfiles, a GUI login will fail (one reason for it anyway) & you're logged out without message. This is likely only an issue if your allocated disk space was small (should be fine if you used 25GB or larger which is recommended).

Comment: I was able to get the OS back up has been down not sure what happen but still having the same issue. Click on settings and it goes to login screen closes out all browsers and apps have to log back in. As far as space goes this is it: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           753M  2.4M  750M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   39G  8.5G   28G  24% /
tmpfs           3.7G   85M  3.6G   3% /dev/shm
Should I reinstall os?

Answer (score 1):

Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu and upate nvidia drivers by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks...will do..

Comment: If you were using the 390 driver, it hasn't been updated for the new 5.3 kernel. I had this trouble as well.

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           753M  2.4M  750M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   39G  8.5G   28G  24% /
tmpfs           3.7G   85M  3.6G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/

Answer (score 0):

It is built into my Lenovo Desktop system that runs two operating systems windows 10 & Ubuntu, however never really had a problem before until now..

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? And who is built in your system?

Comment: Lenovo built it

Comment: Should I install OS over again--I also notice that there is a new OS 19 but I tried to upgrade to that recent one , however system took me back to login screen again..No upgrade can be performed.